Is there an app or tool I can use to make it so that a script will run every time a certain application launches or terminates, without polling?
I want to run a simple shell script any time one of a few different applications terminate. I can identify the applications by their filename, bundle ID, or full path, so any method that can use those will work.
Is there any way to do this using an existing app, feature, or tool? I'm trying to avoid writing a script that just polls regularly and checks whether one of the apps is running.

One way would be to use some AppleScriptObjC to add an observer for NSWorkSpace's NSWorkspaceDidTerminateApplicationNotification.  It wouldn't be polling, but a script application would stay open to get the notification.  From there you can just look if the app is one you are interested in.

@red_menace I was figuring if need be I could write an app that does that. However I'm hoping there's an existing app or tool out there that I can make use of so I don't have to write everything myself. I've clarified my question to the end.

Sounds like something Automator might be able to help with... for example
